# Where clause on SPARQL query

Tags: sparql

How to add a where clause to the following query to select all schools with field 'PROVINCIA' equal to 'Vicenza'?

```
PREFIX miur: <http://www.miur.it/ns/miur#>
PREFIX miur: <http://www.miur.it/ns/miur#>
Select ?AnnoScolastico ?AreaGeografica ?Regione ?Provincia ?CodiceIstitutoRiferimento ?DenominazioneIstitutoRiferimento ?CodiceScuola ?DenominazioneScuola ?IndirizzoScuola ?CAPScuola ?CodiceComuneScuola ?DescrizioneComune ?DescrizioneCaratteristicaScuola ?DescrizioneTipologiaGradoIstruzioneScuola ?IndicazioneSedeDirettivo ?IndicazioneSedeOmnicomprensivo ?IndirizzoEmailScuola ?IndirizzoPecScuola ?SitoWebScuola ?SedeScolastica 
{graph ?g 
{ ?S miur:ANNOSCOLASTICO ?AnnoScolastico. ?S miur:AREAGEOGRAFICA ?AreaGeografica. ?S miur:CAPSCUOLA ?CAPScuola. ?S miur:CODICECOMUNESCUOLA ?CodiceComuneScuola. ?S miur:CODICEISTITUTORIFERIMENTO ?CodiceIstitutoRiferimento. ?S miur:CODICESCUOLA ?CodiceScuola. ?S miur:DENOMINAZIONEISTITUTORIFERIMENTO ?DenominazioneIstitutoRiferimento. ?S miur:DENOMINAZIONESCUOLA ?DenominazioneScuola. ?S miur:DESCRIZIONECARATTERISTICASCUOLA ?DescrizioneCaratteristicaScuola. ?S miur:DESCRIZIONECOMUNE ?DescrizioneComune. ?S miur:DESCRIZIONETIPOLOGIAGRADOISTRUZIONESCUOLA ?DescrizioneTipologiaGradoIstruzioneScuola. ?S miur:INDICAZIONESEDEDIRETTIVO ?IndicazioneSedeDirettivo. ?S miur:INDICAZIONESEDEOMNICOMPRENSIVO ?IndicazioneSedeOmnicomprensivo. ?S miur:INDIRIZZOEMAILSCUOLA ?IndirizzoEmailScuola. ?S miur:INDIRIZZOPECSCUOLA ?IndirizzoPecScuola. ?S miur:INDIRIZZOSCUOLA ?IndirizzoScuola. ?S miur:PROVINCIA ?Provincia. ?S miur:REGIONE ?Regione. ?S miur:SITOWEBSCUOLA ?SitoWebScuola. optional {?S miur:SEDESCOLASTICA ?SedeScolastica } }
} LIMIT 50
```

I am a newbie to sparql

Comment: Take a look at this -->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078966/multiple-sparql-insert-where-queries-in-a-single-request#:~:text=Yes%2C%20this%20is%20possible.%20In%20fact%2C%20your%20example,Sensor%3Atest1%20%27testValue1%27.%20%7D%3B%20INSERT%20%7B%20%3Fsubject2%20Sensor%3Atest2%20%27newValue2%27.

Comment: not that I know your data not the schema, but you could try adding `?S miur:PROVINCIA "Vicenza" .` if your dataset is really just using literals to denote locations of the schools. (maybe a language tag is missing, but as I said, nobody knows your data ...)